# Spring Webflux SecurityValidate OAuth2 JWT Token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

We are using Spring Security Webflux in our resource server where we want to intercept the JWT token sent by client app in Authorization header.
The JWT token is a standard Google token.
Post receiving the token we wwant to perform following:

- If token missing, send 401
- If token present, call Google's API to validate token and get user details like email
- If token expired, send 401

I don't find any clear example to do the same with Spring Security webflux.
Kindly help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your microservice, you can use `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server` dependency and set it in your configuration property:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=<oidc_google_issuer-uri>
```

Spring Security OAuth2 will work for you and complete all steps mentioned above

Let me know if you get your answer